# '${workspaceFolder}' can not be resolved. Please open a folder.' on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Wondering if you could assist. Really challenging in determining a solution to this from my research.

I downloaded **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** two weeks ago, and have come across an error when I try to debug a file. The file appears to open but once I run the debugger it shows accordingly:

[image]

> Variable ${workspaceFolder} can not be resolved. Please open a folder.

Can't seem to find or replicate a similar solution. I've also tried to reinstall Visual Studio Code (no easy feat). I'm trying to at least understand the problem and its source.

The file is a `.js` file that I've been working on; running a simple function. It is not meant to operate in tandem with a larger workspace/program.

Comment: You have to reveal your launch.json file as part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest Visual Studio 1.44, make sure to upgrade to 1.44.2.

The issue [`microsoft/vscode` issue 94725](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94725) has been resolved.
It featured the same error message:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9964210/78838126-65c76d80-79ed-11ea-8572-a092f1576dbc.png]

> After some investigation the problem is the following for the workspace configuration our debug extensions appends the following attribute
>
> ```
> __workspaceFolder:'${workspaceFolder}'
> ```
>
> And the configuration resolver properly tries to resolve this and complains because the scope of the folder is not specified.
>   In a multi root workspace scope has to be specified, otherwise the resolver does not know against which folder to resolve the variables.
>
> Proposed fix: the node extension which adds this attribute should scope it if it sees that we are in a multi root folder.
>   So instead of `${workspaceFolder}` use `${FOLDER_NAME:workspaceFolder}`.

This is fixed in [commit ae97613](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-node-debug/commit/ae976130332b343ae4579e0dec9920dfb1956fe1).

Comment: I get `error cwd ${FOLDER_NAME:workspaceFolder} does not exist`. Part of `workspace.json` is `{"path": "../../../../.oh-my-zsh/custom"}` -> relative path, created by `File Add Folder to Workspace`.

Comment: adding to the comment above next to `cwd` : `"program": "${file}"`

Comment: @Timo OK. Can you ask a separate question with the version of your OS and VSCode used?

Comment: ok, I get the error after having deleted `launch.json`. I just want to use `workspace.json` and set `launch` config there. I get the error with `zshdb` and did not have a config entry in `launch.json`, but in `workspace.json`.

Comment: @Timo So did you resolve your issue? (if not, that would be better addressed in a separate question, as I commented above)

Comment: New situation: if I put the config in `launch.json` in my `code/user`folder, I get in the debug selection a `bash-deb (User)` and start it. Then it works. If I start `bash-deb(workspace)` with same config in `workspace.json` then I get `unable to determine workspace folder`. So this might be a new question as it should work with `(workspace)`.

Comment: Another finding is that with `python` and `powershell` debug it works in both `(workspace)` and `(user)` debug mode.

Comment: @Timo Indeed, that would be best addressed as a separate question: let me know when you create it, and I will follow it.

Comment: [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67910200/vscode-debug-not-working-with-workspace-config)

Answer (score 17):

In VScode go to file --> Add folder to workspace and select the folder where the program files are located.

Comment: So after I did this, I could solve the second part of the problem with VSCODE with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387842/how-do-i-compile-and-run-a-c-sharp-code-in-vscode-linux-ubuntu by editing the program: and substituting with the net5.0 core, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "program files" ? The .exe file ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old already and the answers may have been correct but none worked for me on vscode *v1.57.1* at the time of this comment on *30.06.2021*

I had to replace `${workspaceFolder}` with `${workspaceFolder:my-folder-name}` in my `*.code-workspace` file

Ref: [Variables scoped per workspace folder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_variables-scoped-per-workspace-folder)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `${workspaceFolder}` with `${FOLDER_NAME:workspaceFolder}` in your `*.code-workspace` file. (from [here][1])

By the way, same goes to `${workspaceRoot}`, you can replace it with `${FOLDER_NAME:workspaceRoot}`.

Any more folder variables ca be fixed with this `FOLDER_NAME:` prefix? My workspaces did not use them so far.

Worked for me in `Version: 1.44.2`.

Comment: As per latest update, it is `${workspaceFolder:<FolderName>}`; [Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_debugging)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a multiroot workspace and was able to resolve this by explicitly defining the java.project.sourcePaths under settings in my workspace configuration such that it looks like the following:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "folderA"
        },
        {
            "path": "folderB"
        },
        {
            "path": "folderC"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "java.project.sourcePaths": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/folderA"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently had this problem and so did I read the answers above but being a beginner I was unable to solve it .In my answer I don't have exactly what you should do but I will show what worked for me.

1. Go to the explorer and you will see there is no folder added.
2. Browse for ***.vscode*** folder and select it.
3. Issue solved {this atleast worked for me.It**(.vscode)** had .json extension file in it}.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, but I solved it this way:
1- open VS Code as administrator
2- open the sheet
3- debugging with no problem :)

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohigR.png)

I just create a file.json that they can debug.