# VS code, julia linter doesn't work (on mac)

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, linter

having assured myself that julia is enabled and that the linter is too (in vs code settings: Julia › Lint: Run), i get syntax highlighting on my xxx.jl script but no linting at all.

im on the latest vs code + latest **julia 1.07 extension** + latest macosx.
i did a clean installation of vs code, wiping all old related folders prior to installation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53839847/11608725)
so julia is the only extension/package installed, no conflicts should be present.

what am i missing?

thanks!

---

edit/update:

i also found that i can NOT run an open script (via the leftmost button) [image: run with leftmost triangle]

a pop-up says [image: '${workspaceFolder}' can not be resolved. Please open a folder. open launch.json]

and clicking on open launch.json gives [image]

from which point on im pretty much stuck. googling around, a couple of very similar issues appeared (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61284896/11608725, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94725#issuecomment-612062020), but which should presumably have been fixed with vs code 1.44 and i am on 1.49.

perhaps the no-linting is related to this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Julia Formatter 0.3.0 for vs code? This has always worked for me.

Comment: thanks riley, but the formatter is supposed to also do linting?

Answer (score 0):

similar message *"Please first open a folder in order to .."* pretty annoyingly appeared, my end, on a different platform [Win] [Visual Studio Code version: 1.56.2], too

meaning : it's likely the workflow/settings logic specific to VS Code, not an os/platform issue as such

all problems solved, my end, simply by

- after launching VS Code
- via *"File"* > *"Open Folder..."* : just do **first** -- before doing anything else in VS Code and/or with code-files -- **open** the current/working project folder [ie. the very folder with a *".code-workspace"*-file in it for the given project (source file dir) ]