# Vscode Bash Debug not working with workspace config in Linux, but with user config

Tags: json, bash, debugging, visual-studio-code, workspace

#### Bash Debug in VScode not working as it should

I use [`Bashdb`](https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug) extension for `VScode`

##### Environment

- Ubuntu 20_04
- Vscode 1.56.2
- launch.json in `code/user`
- workspace.json in `code/Workspaces/1619293380488`

##### Situation

- In Run View there is a `bash-deb (User)` config and I can start it (defined in launch.json). It works
- If I start bash-deb(workspace) with same config as launch.json defined in workspace.json I get:

`unable to determine workspace folder`.

##### Expected

it should work with `(workspace)` as well.

##### Note

- `python` and `powershell` debug  work in both `(workspace)` and `(user)` config
- in `Windows`, `launch.json` does not exist. If I try to call it from `F1`, `launch.json` directs to `workspace.code-workspace` to the `configurations` area.

Configuration used in both `json`:

```
 {
    "type": "bashdb",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Bash-Debug",
    "program": "${file}"
 },
```

Comment: Hello, @Timo, have you managed to resolve it? If so, how?

Comment: @b.g. No, I still use `launch.json`.